# Which black berry plant for north side of the house?

Tags: blackberry

When I Google for blackberry types, very often the website only mentions [thorn less](https://thefruitgrove.com/the-best-tasting-thornless-blackberries-9-top-picks/) blackberries. And then [this one](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/blackberries-grow-part-shade-67693.html) says blackberries should get full sun, and then also talks about shade.

Some sites says that late sommer blackberries are to be preferred, because they are less likely to get illnesses.

**Question**

Can someone guide me on which type to get, then they are going to be planted on the north side of the house?

Comment: Fruiting plants need a lot of energy. If you plant them there, even if they do grow, the fruit production will be far less and ripen much later, maybe not at all. If you want something ornamental, maybe choose another type of plant?

Comment: Interesting. I were under the impression that they didn't needed light as they often grow in the forest. So I guess some sort of flower bush then...